# Decrypting file with Blackbox in GitLab CI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gnupg

I encrypted a file on my local machine with blackbox and now want to decrypt it on GitLab CI. I already stored the private key as an environment variable ($GPG_PRIVATE_KEY), but now I can't decrypt it.

My .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
simple_test:
      script:
      - apt-get update -qq && apt-get -yqq install gnupg2
      - git clone https://github.com/StackExchange/blackbox.git
      - cd blackbox
      - make manual-install
      - cd ..
      - gpg2 -v --import <(echo "$GPG_PRIVATE_KEY")
      - GPG=gpg2 blackbox_postdeploy
      - ruby test.rb
```

The error message:

```
gpg: directory '/root/.gnupg' created
gpg: keybox '/root/.gnupg/pubring.kbx' created
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found
```

I have tried various solutions, from changing the gpg2 import section, to playing around with different gpg versions.